# QEMU debugging:: Warning:TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX

Tags: linux, qemu

i have a problem with the qemu, first i creat a image

```
sudo qemu-img create -f qcow2 alpine.img 2G
```

and then when i try to lunch the alpine machine it blocks in this message error

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 512 -drive file=./alpine.img,format=qcow2  -boot  d -cdrom alpine-standard-3.10.3-x86.iso -display vnc=:0

qemu-system-x86_64: warning: TCG doesn't support requested feature: CPUID.01H:ECX.vmx [bit 5]
```

anyone have been in the same situation
thanks

Comment: This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55232390/205548).

Comment: @JanWillems The answer you linked doesn't answer this question. This question is about VMX. The linked answer is about SSE4.2.